# Increase width of textbox inside bootstrap form-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to increase the width of the text boxes inside a form-inline. But, I am not able to increase the width. Even the associated label is getting hidden below the text box.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="UserNameTextBox">Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="UserNameTextBox" placeholder="User Name">
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="UserEmailTextBox">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="UserEmailTextBox" placeholder="User Email">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/Vimalan/mt30tfpv/2/

**Current:**

[image]

**Expected:** (length of the text box is increased)

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the text boxes using this CSS code:

```
.form-inline .form-group input {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

### Update (another solution)

Set label and input `display` to `inline-block` as below:

```
.myform label, .myform input {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

and set input width to 80% as below:

```
.myform input {
    width:80%;
}
```

Give the name container (input+label) 5 boostrap columns `col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5`

Give the email container (input+label) 5 boostrap columns `col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5`

Give the button 2 boostrap columns `col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2`

Output:

[image]

**### Check it out.**

Comment: thanks for your response. Is it possible to just use what is available in bootstrap css to achieve this?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh : Please check the answer again. This solution is better that the first (boostrap+css solution)